# I have a code in that i need add vertical and horizontal lines between each image

Tags: ios

[I have code like this and i need to insert vertical and horizontal lines between images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m4Fm.png)

```
self.searchBR.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.default
        self.title = (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "selctedCity") as! String)

        mainCollectionImgArray = ["headset.png","achievement.png","car.png",
                                  "configuration-gear.png","Cleaning.png",
                                  "portfolio.png","vaccine.png","book.png","Sports.png","Food.png","Events.png","Arts&Entertainment.png","Health&Beauty.png","Clothes&Accessories.png","Baby.png","Toys.png","Electronics.png","RealEstate.png","Furniture.png","Travel.png","Pets.png","Manufactures.png","Used&Rentals.png"]
        self.loadCategoryData()
        self.loadSubcategoriesData()
        self.loadSuperSubCategories()

        self.mainCollectionView.reloadData()
        topCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func locationButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let LocationViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(LocationViewController!, animated: true)
    }
```

i want to add vertical and horizontal lines between images kindly somebody help me

Comment: Can you post of screenshot of what you want to achieve? Might help.

Comment: i have added the screen shot for the same..

Comment: Hi,Vijay Issue is solved   ,thank you